# String compare using regex

Tags: c++, regex, string

I have a string say:

`std::string s1 = "@Hello$World@";`

I want to match it with another string but only certain characters:

`std::string s2 = "_Hello_World_";`

The strings must have same length and exactly match ignoring the `_` characters which can be anything. In other words, I want to match the sequence of "Hello" and "World" at same indexes.

I could use a loop here ignoring those indexes but I want to know if I can do this with regex expressions?

Comment: In regex, a dot matches any character (except newlines), so your regex would have to look like `.Hello.World.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just use `std::regex_match` like so:

```
std::string string("@Hello$World@");
std::regex regex("^.Hello.World.$");
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::regex_match(string, regex);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52615da41bd11c06)

The `.` (dots) in the regex mean "any character", `^` means "starting of the string" and `$` means ending of the string.

Comment: Is it also possible to match any lower case character instead of just any character?

Comment: @user963241 Yes, [with classes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/551e20b1401797af). Please, if you have any other question, open a new question instead of asking them here. The reason for this is that Stack Overflow is optimized for single straight forward questions + related answers; questions and answers in comments may not even be indexed well by search engines.

Comment: Thanks. I want know just one thing related to the answer: if it is really necessary to use `^` and `$` in regex. I think it works without them as well.

Comment: @user963241 Depends on whether you want to match  `.Hello.World.` anywhere in a string or match only if the whole string matches `.Hello.World.`.

Comment: But it still doesn't work for [anywhere](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7854143cd7a4639)

Comment: @user963241 I understand this is an old answer, but this was one of the top hits in a Google search for "c++ regex compare".
[Note that regex_match will only successfully match a regular expression to an entire character sequence, whereas std::regex_search will successfully match subsequences.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match)
Effectively, using `^` and `$` in a `regex_match` call is redundant and using BOTH in a `regex_search` call is equivalent to `regex_match` if you don't use them INSIDE an alternation: `(^Hello)|(World$)`.

Answer (score 3):

The '.' (dot) operator inside a regex pattern will act as a substitute for any char. Below you have 3 strings with different separators that are matched by the pat variable...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    regex pat(".Hello.World.");
    // regex pat(.Hello.World., regex_constants::icase); // for case insensitivity

    string str1 = "_Hello_World_";
    string str2 = "@Hello@World@";
    string str3 = "aHellobWorldc";

    bool match1 = regex_match(str1, pat);
    bool match2 = regex_match(str2, pat);
    bool match3 = regex_match(str3, pat);

    cout << (match1 ? "Matched" : "Not matched") << endl;
    cout << (match2 ? "Matched" : "Not matched") << endl;
    cout << (match3 ? "Matched" : "Not matched") << endl;


    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```